# the error happening in the gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

When I type the instruction

```
gnuplot>plot "cbr_delay"
```

in the terminal,the system show error as follows

```
          0.100000 0.038706
^
"cbr_delay", line 1: invalid command
```

the file cbr_delay is shown

```
0.100000 0.038706
0.108000 0.038706
0.116000 0.038706
0.124000 0.038706
0.132000 0.038706
0.140000 0.038706
0.148000 0.038706
0.156000 0.038706
0.164000 0.038706
0.172000 0.038706
0.180000 0.038706
0.188000 0.038706
0.196000 0.038706
0.204000 0.038706
0.212000 0.038706
0.220000 0.038706
0.228000 0.038706
0.236000 0.038706
0.244000 0.038706
0.252000 0.038706
```

what can i do to avoid the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you're typing that in *exactly* which your shell interprets as:

```
gnuplot cbr_delay > plot
```

What this means to the shell is that gnuplot should run the script cbr_delay and put the standard output stream in a file called "plot".  You could test this by looking for a file called "plot" in the current directory.

What you want to do is *first* get to the gnuplot prompt by simply typing `gnuplot`.  Then you can type in your gnuplot commands:

```
gnuplot  #enter gnuplot

#at this point, you should see a gnuplot prompt which looks like "gnuplot>"
#now enter your gnuplot command
plot "cbr_delay"
```

Comment: @george -- Yeah, it confused me for a couple minutes as well.